# Simplification in induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't really get how to get from `(2^k+1)/2 to (2^k)`

```
Use mathematical induction to show that when n is an exact power of 2, the solution of the recurrence:
```

[image: here]

Comment: $2^{k+1}=2^k2^1=2^k2$; now divide both sides by $2$

Comment: I got it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$2^{k+1}=2^k2^1=2^k2,$$ so dividing both sides by $2$ we get $$2^{k+1}/2=2^k$$